# How to call a python command line tool from a web service when API endpoint is hit?

Tags: python, bash, api, web-services, command-line-interface

I have a working command line tool that does a thing well written in Python. It takes a few parameters from the command line using the Argparse package.

Now we have a small web service with a nice endpoint to hit to trigger this command line tool. So now the JSON payload has to contain the former-command-line parameters.

How do I pass the JSON payload to the python script without jumping into my OS environment and calling a bash command or something like that? Is there a way to do this with minimal changes to the CLI python script? In case we want to keep the CLI functionality for local executions?

I'm just not sure on the proper way to do this. Thanks

Here's the code "template" if that helps:

```py
arser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
parser.add_argument("arg1", ...)
args = parser.parse_args()

actual_param = args.arg1
.
.
.
def main_logic_flow(parameter):
    ....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_logic_flow(actual_param)
```

Comment: Is the web service written in Python too? In that case you can simply import your `main_logic_flow` method and call it. If not, you should call it as a shell command.

Comment: It is a small flask API so yes. I kinda see the path that way but I wasn't sure about how this is supposed to be done appropriately. Say it weren't also written in python? I imagine it isn't a unique situation but maybe I need to re-write part of the script and focus on triggering from API, and forget CLI input? Thanks @Selcuk

Comment: if you can't import then use `subprocess.run("python script.py arg1 arg2", shell=True)` or `subprocess.run(["python", "script.py", "arg1", "arg2"])`. The same with any other program.